# fragmenting data from text file into list of facts to prolog file

Tags: file, parsing, io, prolog, sicstus-prolog

I want to separate the data file into list of facts like `functor(arg1, arg2, ..., argN)` which the name of functor is the *uppercase* line and the arguments are the *lowercase* lines  that follow them, 
subsequently, new clauses are saved in a prolog file created at the execution

**file.txt**

```
FUNCTOR1
arg1 
arg2
FUNCTOR2
arg1
arg2
arg3
FUNCTOR3
arg1
arg2
arg3
arg4
```

**result :**

```
?- split_data_to_facts('file.txt',List,'file.pl').
List = ['functor1(arg1,arg2)','functor2(arg1,arg2,arg3)','functor3(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)'].
```

**file.pl**

*"." will be appended as the last*

```
functor1(arg1,arg2).        
functor2(arg1,arg2,arg3).
functor3(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4).
```

after building and compiling the **new** prolog file `file.pl`:

```
?- functor2(X,Y,Z).
X=arg1,
Y=arg2,
Z=arg3;
yes
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i try to parse file and puting data into List

Comment: Where did you get stuck? You can make use of the `=../2` operator. For example, `X =.. [functor, a, b]` is `X = functor(a, b)`.

Comment: the list is like :List=['FUNCTOR1','arg1','arg2','FUNCTOR2','arg1','arg2','arg3'|...]

Comment: You will need to split up your list first. You should be able to write a little, very simple, list processing code to do that. Or, split it up while you're reading it in from the file so that the functors are separate.

Comment: u know how to convert uppercase atom to lowercase in `sicstus-prolog` ?

Comment: I don't use sicstus Prolog, but if you look in the documentation, I'm sure it should be easy to find. Look for atom and string processing predicates.

Comment: sadly I find nothing  but I attempting to use to use char_codes/2 and adding 32 like `X=a, to_upper(X,Y) :- char_code(X,N),N1 is N-32,char_code(Y,N1)`

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume a builtin read_line_to_codes/2 is available: then you could apply a *lookahead* of one line:

```
process_file(Path) :-
  open(Path, read, In),
  read_line_to_codes(In, Line1),
  read_line_to_codes(In, Line2), % assume not empty
  process_lines(Line2, [Line1], In, Facts),
  maplist(writeln, Facts).  % just for test

process_lines(end_of_file, LastFactDef, In, [LastFact]) :-
  lines_fact(LastFactDef, LastFact),
  close(In).
process_lines([U|Us], LastFactDef, In, [LastFact|Facts]) :-
  upper_lower(U, _),
  lines_fact(LastFactDef, LastFact),
  read_line_to_codes(In, Line),
  process_lines(Line, [[U|Us]], In, Facts).
process_lines(Last, Lines, In, Facts) :-
  read_line_to_codes(In, Line),
  process_lines(Line, [Last|Lines], In, Facts).

lines_fact(Lines, Fact) :-
  reverse(Lines, [FunctorUpper|ArgCodes]),
  maplist(make_lower, FunctorUpper, FunctorCodes),
  maplist(atom_codes, [Functor|Args], [FunctorCodes|ArgCodes]),
  Fact =.. [Functor|Args].

% if uppercase get lowercase
upper_lower(U, L) :-
  between(0'A, 0'Z, U), L is 0'a + U - 0'A.

make_lower(C, L) :- upper_lower(C, L) ; L = C.
```

running a test in SWI-Prolog (where we have by default available read_line_to_codes/2 and between/3):

```
?- process_file('/home/carlo/test/file.txt').
functor1(arg1 ,arg2)
functor2(arg1,arg2,arg3)
functor3(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)
true
```

Comment: thanks , but can you explain how the Args appended to her functors ?

Comment: Each line not beginning with an uppercase is 'pushed' into LastFactDef. Then =.. (so called univ) arranges the functor and arguments

Comment: sorry,which line, is it process_lines/4 ?, and why this [[U|Us]] (example)

Comment: first argument of process_lines/4 is a list of character codes. To test the first char the list is 'decomposed' in the head, and 'recomposed' when it's pushed, to be used later as functor

Comment: can u explain this [[X|Xs]] ?